# ArcObjects Runtime Binding 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I installed the ArcOjbects SDK (if I remember correctly) and in visual studio I have referenced the needed assemblies.  Namely ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.

When in stepping through in debug mode I hit this routine:

```
void BindingArcGISRuntime(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //ProductCode[] supportedRuntimes = new ProductCode[] { ProductCode.Desktop };
            //foreach (ProductCode c in supportedRuntimes)
            //{
            //    if (RuntimeManager.Bind(c))
            //        return;
            //}


            if (!RuntimeManager.Bind(ProductCode.Desktop))
            {
                // Failed to bind, announce and force exit
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid ArcGIS runtime binding. Application will shut down.");
                System.Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

But I don't hit the

"Console.WriteLine("Invalid ArcGIS runtime binding. Application will shut down.");"

piece

Then straight to this auto-generated routine:

```
if (RuntimeManager.ActiveRuntime == null)
            {
                EventHandler temp = ResolveBindingEvent;
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    temp(this, new EventArgs());
                }
            }

            return Initialize();
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you performed authorization?
Otherwise, license binding will fail

You can see if your software is authorized in ArcGIS Administrator

Answer (score 1):

i think you should drag the licence key into a window, and copy this code in program.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ESRI.ArcGIS;

namespace Geoleve
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            if (!RuntimeManager.Bind(ProductCode.Engine))
            {
                if (!RuntimeManager.Bind(ProductCode.Desktop))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to bind to ArcGIS runtime. Application will be shut down.");
                    return;
                }
            }


            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

if you are using .NET framework 3.5 in 64 bits machine you may have another [error and here the solution](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37879)